# Confused about marker Interfaces and JVM in JAVA

Tags: java, serialization

I am perplexed. I read some threads on stack-overflow regarding marker interfaces in JAVA.

[On this thread it is written as:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829437/how-marker-interface-are-identified-by-jvm)

Marker interfaces aren't 'identified by the JVM' at all. They're identified by the Java code that is interested in them, for example ObjectOutputStream, via the instanceof operator.

Then in comments, it is asserted that:
The implementation in ObjectOutputStream checks if the object has implemented the Serializable interface, if yes perform wirteObject(objectToBeSerialized). So even we can write a marker interface and write a code that checks if an object is an instance of that marker interface and take appropriate action on it then.

[On another thread it is written as:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751661/with-out-implementing-a-serializable-interface-is-it-possible-to-make-a-class-pe)

Only Serializable will mark an object as being compatible with Java's built-in serialization machinery.
You can create other empty interfaces, but they won't mean the same thing. Each interface is distinct, even if it defines the same set of methods.

**So my question is** can we make classes that use serialization without implementing corresponding JAVA's built in interface?
Or is it a special interface that is mandatory to be implemented?
(Asumme, I don't want to use instance of)

Comment: Javadoc of [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html): *Only objects that support the `java.io.Serializable` interface can be written to streams*. --- Isn't that clear enough? If you want to serialize an object using `ObjectOutputStream`, you **must** make the object implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Yes it is clear now. The other answers made me confused. Thanks for the help. 
From the first answer I thought, It is just conventional to implement Serializable interface and then we validate our objects later with instance of. But it was because ObjectOutputStream can only work with objects implementing the said interface.

Comment: The first one was correct when it said *"Marker interfaces aren't 'identified by the JVM' at all"*, because there is no such thing as a marker interface, as far as the JVM is concerned. A marker interface is a term used to describe empty interfaces that cause *some code* to behave differently, simply because a class implements the interface. In this case, "some code" means code in the Java Runtime Library, i.e. in the `ObjectOutputStream` class. The **Java Runtime Library** and the **Java Virtual Machine** (JVM) are entire different things. A **Java Runtime Environment** (JRE) includes both.